# MQ-like Java library/framework for processing large data with fault-tolerance and re-injecting of large messages

Tags: java, scala, mq

The requirements are: several services produce lots of requests with data streams (1-10 megabytes per request) and several consumers process these requests atomically.

So the request data **can not be split**. The key requirement is that if some consumer fails to process request - this request must be **re-injected** into queue and sent to different consumer. Processing of single request may take tens of minutes. Consumer may 'die' during the processing, so some sort of task monitoring is required.

I considered so far

- http://kafka.apache.org/
- http://storm-project.net/
- http://activemq.apache.org/
- http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/

but neither of them seems to meet my requirements. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your requirements (> 1 MB per request, processing > 10 minutes) ... is it still messaging?

I would just put it in a database (RDBMS). If polling is not acceptable, I'd consider triggers/stored procedures in the database. Stored procedures written in Scala work perfectly in Oracle and PostgreSql.

Comment: sure it's not a true messaging, but something close enough. I finally decided to go with plain old database.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for activemq, but between kafka and storm I would choose storm. It's not clear what do you mean saying *fails to process request*, but if storm worker fails completely (i.e. doesn't respond to heartbeats) Storm master (nimbus) may reassign the task from dead worker to another (perhaps, on different machine).

See also [Understanding the parallelism of a Storm topology](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology)

Kafka is a dead simple message broker and without some highlevel coordination it cannot do things you've mentioned out-of-the-box.